# Implementing loading gif while processing data and fade in animation on jQuery form UI

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery form (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit a form on this page: http://licf.ronaldboadi.com/practice/test.html. Here is the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#submitform',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 

        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#camperapplicationForm').submit(function() { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 
}); 

// pre-submit callback 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData); 
   // var formElement = jqForm[0]; 

    alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
    return true; 
} 

// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
} 
</script>
```

I have settled on using a loading gif while I am processing data and once I have the div ready I can use a fade in animation.

This would involve adding a simple img element (loading gif) to the div when I submit the form. When I have the result, for example in the success method of an $.ajax call, I need to hide the div, replace the img element with the result I got from the server then add the fade in animation.

But I've been wondering how I can implement the below code into my current code... any ideas how to?

```
//Assuming you have a $.ajax request to submit the form:

//add the loading gif
$('#submitform').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

//send your form data
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    data: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
        param3: 3
    },
    success: function(data){
        //hide the div, assuming the process.php return simple html code to your page update the div content, then add the fade in animation
        $('#submitform').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the link that is relevant? Eg, construct a small, silo'd question out of this. This way it's easier to answer and future people will be able to follow this without that site having to stay up in it's current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like so:

```
var siteUrl = 'http://localhost/';

//send your form data
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    data: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2,
        param3: 3
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('#main').append('<div class="loading"><img src="' + siteUrl + 'resources/imgs/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.loading').remove();
        //hide the div, assuming the process.php return simple html code to your page update the div content, then add the fade in animation
        $('#submitform').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

## Update

my solution is for the jQuery ajax code you posted. For the malsup according to their options documentation http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object, you may try:

```
//Show loading image before submit
beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) { 
   $('#main').append('<div class="loading"><img src="' + siteUrl + 'resources/imgs/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
}
//Remove loading image after response
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('.loading').remove();
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
}
```

That's the idea...

Comment: How would I implement this feature into the jquery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) I'm using?

Comment: check edit, but also read the options page to see where to implement the addon code correctly so it does what you need

Comment: Everytime I add the beforeSubmit function it seems to break the jquery form process by jumping directly to process.php instead of remaining on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop events to show/hide your loading indicator. This is called automatically by jQuery whenever you make an ajax call.

```
$("#loadingIndicator")
.bind('ajaxStart', function() {
   $(this).show();
})
.bind('ajaxStop', function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: How would I implement this feature into the jquery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) I'm using?